# PDO: Fetch class option to send fields to constructor as array

Tags: php, oop, orm, pdo

I am wondering whether or not it is possible to elegantly map the results of a PDO query to an array member in a class rather than have them floating about as public properties of that object.

Say I have the (condensed) following:

```
class DBObject {

    protected
        $record = array();

    function __construct(array $record) {
        if(!empty($record)) {
            $this->loadRecord($record);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want to call the constructor with an array of values passed from the database, rather than use __set or any other weird methods. So using PDO's existing API would be great.

My rough `get_all` function at the moment has got this far:

```
static function get_all() {
    $class = get_called_class();
    $results = DB::factory()->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $class . ' ORDER BY ID');
    $results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $class);
    return $results;
}
```

**NB: I'm running PHP 5.3 and MySQL through PDO, and already know this problem is solveable using __set, but I explicitly want to avoid using it in favour of something more performant.**

Comment: Are you aware that this code is tightly coupled to the name of `DB` class , and that it violates "Law of Demeter" ?

Comment: Yes, it violates LoD. No, your comment won't fix my problem. Besides, tightly coupling a Model to a Database is better than using a global (which, IMO, is infinitely worse.)

Comment: if it was a solution , it would have been in the "Answers" section. Ad no , i thing global variables are no different from static calls.

Comment: In fact, how can you say the factory pattern violates the Law of Demeter when you need a base class that waits until runtime to instantiate something based on developer/tester parameters? Perhaps you're confusing it with the singleton pattern?

Comment: no i am not confusing it , because you are using "factory method" ( which actually least to some additional problems ). And that is not what causes it to violate LoD. You are reaching though the factory to get to an object to get to the method. That is the problem. Of course fact that the factory was never provided for that object is a violation too.

Comment: OK then. If you, in your infinite wisdom, were to resolve this problem (instead of answering my question), what would you do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8338/discussion-between-will-morgan-and-teresko)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed previous code

---

Right, can't you do something like this:

```
class DBObject {

    protected $record = array();

    function __construct($record = null) {
        if(null === $record){
            $obj_vars = get_object_vars($this);
            $cls_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($this));
            $this->$record = array_diff_key($obj_vars, $cls_vars);
        }else{
            $this->record = $record;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this however is that the values are still available as public members.
But what it will do is compare 'pre-defined' (class) members to the actual (object) members.

Since PDO will create new members in the object you can use array_diff_key to get the 'new' members.

Yes, this will still not pass them through your constructor.

Comment: I don't see how this loads anything in to my $record array.

Comment: It will not. You said you were trying to hide 'public' properties created by fetchObject.

Comment: Hmm, seems kind of fragile. Whether or not the variables are public is irrelevant to me; I want to organise the data in such a way that there is clear separation between the DB record data and the object's state/other miscellaneous variables.

Comment: This is not really fragile, unless you call the constructor multiple times on the same object (possible.) PDO Will first create the members, and only then it will call the constructor. Therefor in the constructor there is a seperation between 'class members', 'normal object members', 'pdo-generated members' and 'runtime-generated members'. The latter can simply not exist yet (unless created in a parents constructor) during object creation. So it seems quite safe to me

Comment: Alright, I get you. I've benchmarked your solution against __set and it's faster. If you could update your code to incorporate the constructor parameter (just for safety) then I'll accept your answer. Cheers :)
PS: benchmark source here: http://pastebin.com/2MemcrFh

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass arguments to a constructor to make a class with private members using PDO::FETCH_CLASS. You can do something like this:

```
<?php
class Songs
{  

    private $artist;
    private $title;

    public function __construct()
    {  
    }

    public function get_artist()
    {
    return $this->artist;
    }

    public function get_title() 
    {
    return $this->title;
    }

    private function set_artist($artist) 
    {
    $this->artist = $artist;
    }

    private function set_title($title) 
    {
    $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

I'm actually doing that on a demo site that I built. It works just fine with PDO::FETCH_CLASS. By default, FETCH_CLASS creates objects by populating the fields BEFORE the constructor. Think of it as bypassing the constructor. And it will do this with private members.

If you'd rather pass arguments to the constructor you can do your query like this:

```
$obj = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Songs', $params);
```

In that case your constructor would look like this:

```
public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->artist = $params[0]['artist'];
    $this->title= $params[0]['title'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using magic [__set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) method:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    protected $record = array();

    function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->record[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'user', 'password');
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');
```

PHP will call this magic method for every non-existent property passing in its name and value.

Comment: Hi. If you had read the OP in full, you will have seen:

NB: I'm running PHP 5.3 and MySQL through PDO, and I know how to solve this problem using __set, but would rather avoid that for the performance penalty.

Comment: Sorry Will, I missed the note obviously. However, I wouldn't be too worried about the performance penalty as it's likely minimal, esp. compared to any penalty added by the DB operation. I've run some tests and it appears that assigning directly to public or non-existing variable is about one order of magnitude quicker than when using the magic setter, but we're talking thousandths v. hundredths of a MILLISECOND (~0.002ms v. ~0.02ms in my system). A DB query alone is usually around 10-100ms, so 4-5 orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Also, bear in mind, that calling a constructor also cost the same as calling any other method, including magic methods.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't want to prematurely optimise (too much) but for loading things in to objects which would be a frequent occurrence I want things to be as light as possible.

Comment: @Janci you sure have a point. However, what if your query, that runs for 0.1s returns 1000 rows. That will be 1000 new objects and suddenly there is a huge difference between 0.002ms and 0.02ms. I guess it all depends on scope. If you will ever only return 10 rows, in 10queries then it will be neglectable.